# In Asmus' "Gambit" run, who or what could have made Joelle immortal?

Tags: marvel, x-men

The 2012-2013 run of *Gambit*, by James Asmus and Clay Mann, introduced Joelle, a lady thief, counterpart and love interest of Gambit.

Throughout the chapters it's shown that something is definitely unusual with Joelle. In issue #12 she reveals that, shortly after her daughter was born, Joelle was given immortality by an unknown man/thing (and apparently saved from imminent death at the same time).

[image: Joelle reveals how she came to be immortal]

The identity of said man/thing, however, is not disclosed as far as I can see into the *Gambit* run. According to [the wikia](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Joelle_(Earth-616)) she only appears in that run ([ComicVine](https://comicvine.gamespot.com/joelle/4005-86115/) says she appears in the 2013 *Wolverine* run, but having read those, she doesn't); in [an interview with CBR](https://www.cbr.com/x-position-asmus-deals-gambit-his-final-hand/), James Asmus said he "knew from the beginning that Joelle would be an accidental immortal, outliving the life she wanted", but doesn't give more info on the source of her power.

Of course it's possible the unknown man/thing is actually *not* a known character, but that's not confirmed either (isn't it?). So, on the off-chance this was not a "just deal with it" plot device, what Marvel character could have enabled Joelle to:

- never age
- breathe a hellish dimension's toxic air unharmed
- be unaffected by Rogue's touch
- only be vulnerable to Hydra's death compound,

all this seemingly for free? Accidental immortality aside, Joelle didn't seem to be forced to give something in return.

Comment: I've read up on her Wiki page, and really the only thing I could find was that she was given immortality so she could be with her daughter. Once her daughter started aging naturally, though, she decided she wanted to die and was killed off.